# AssertionError running SpringBoot unit test using Repository Spring JPA for entities with EntityGraph annotation

Tags: spring-boot, junit, entitygraph

after upgraded from Java11 to Java17 some unit test has becoming failing.
I'm using Java 17 locally existing VM temurin-17.jdk with Springboot 3.0.2 and Junit 5.9.2.

This is the unit test failing now:

```
public class MyServiceTests {

    @Autowired
private MyService myService;

save some data into test database

    @Test
public void doSomethingTest() {
RequestBody body = new RequestBody("...");

B b = myService.doSomething(body);

assertEquals(...);
    }

}
```

This is the service:

```
//....

@Override
public B doSomething(RequestBody request) {

     //Status Ok
B b = new B();

List<UUID> aList = request.getAelements();

Check A elements on the database
Map<UUID, A> aMaps = aRepo.findByUuidIn(aList)
             .stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getUuid, a -> a));

b.setAMaps(aMaps);
     //....
return b;

}
```

This is the repository:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "a-with-b")
List<A> findByUuidIn(List<UUID> uuids);
```

This is the entity 1:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
name = "a-with-b",
attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode(value = "b") }
)
@Table( name = "a", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"someColumnUnique"}))
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
public class A {

    //...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKey(name = "id")
private Map<UUID, B> bMaps;

    //...
}
```

This is the entity 2:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "b")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
public class B {

    // ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @NotNull(message = "A element must not be null")
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private A a;

    // ...
}
```

And finally this is the error:

```
2023-08-30 10:44:21.406  INFO  StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener-end():261 - \[ Session Metrics {
0 nanoseconds spent acquiring 0 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
} \]

java.lang.AssertionError
at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardEntityGraphTraversalStateImpl.traverse(StandardEntityGraphTraversalStateImpl.java:71)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.addFetch(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:6937)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitFetches(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:7099)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.AbstractFetchParent.afterInitialize(AbstractFetchParent.java:32)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.afterInitialize(AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.java:100)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createDomainResult(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1300)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.AbstractSqmPathInterpretation.createDomainResult(AbstractSqmPathInterpretation.java:55)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.lambda$visitSelection$25(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2053)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonList.forEach(Collections.java:4966)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelection(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2048)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectClause(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1951)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQuerySpec(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1819)
...
```

Thanks